# Is there any way to open link that comes from onesignal on webview?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I'm using webview widget in my flutter app I want to open a link when user tap on notification, the link comes from additional data on one signal
I tried to make this but it doesn't work
my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:onesignal/onesignal.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
String _debugLabelString = "";
String url = "https://www.google.com";


@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
initPlatformState();
}

Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
if (!mounted) return;

OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);

OneSignal.shared.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(_requireConsent);

var settings = {
  OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
  OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
};

OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((notification) {
  this.setState(() {
    url = notification.payload.additionalData['url'].toString() ;

  });
});

OneSignal.shared
    .setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  this.setState(() {
  // the value of result.notification.payload.additionalData['url'] = 
  // https://www.facebook.com/
    url = result.notification.payload.additionalData['url'].toString() ;
  });
});


// NOTE: Replace with your own app ID from https://www.onesignal.com
await OneSignal.shared
    .init("086d22bd-5539-4849-9db2-01589fd3429d", iOSSettings: settings);

OneSignal.shared
    .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);


}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
home: new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(
title: const Text('OneSignal Flutter Demo'),
backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 86, 83),
),
body:  WebviewScaffold(
        url: url,

        withJavascript: true,
      )
  ),
);
}
}
```

I put facebook.com on in additional data it show google page not facebook how to make it show the save value the I put on additional data

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: Have you checked what value you're actually receiving?

Comment: Yes, when  the app is on foreground I receiving same value the I gave it in additional data, but when the app in background doesn't change.
and in both it doesn't take me to the specific url when I tapped on notification
 Please I need a solution !

Comment: So you are receiving facebook.com as the value? How to navigate to the correct webview if you're getting the correct url in additionalData is a Flutter question at this point, not a OneSignal question. I'm personally not familiar with Dart/Flutter development so I can really only be of help with OneSignal related questions

Comment: I only get facebook.com value if the app is on foreground if I close it I get the google.com

Answer (score 0):

The `setNotificationReceivedHandler` creates the callback for when a notification is received on the device **in the foreground**.

For the "on notification open" callback (which works for if it is in the background), use the `setNotificationOpened` handler.

[Flutter event handler reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk#section-state-observers).

If you're looking to handle this in the background regardless of whether the notification is opened or not, see [Background Notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications) (note: be prepared to write native code, here)

Comment: I can't get notifications when the app closed or Swiping away.
Is Background Notifications in one signal will solve this issue ??

Comment: Yes, make sure to set up a service extension to handle this